# how to calculate difference of first row and last row fields value in each group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, group-by

I have table with structure like this:

```
+-------+------------------+
| Value |       Date       |
+-------+------------------+
|    10 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |
|    11 | 10/10/2010 10:15 |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:30 |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:45 |
|    17 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |
|    18 | 10/10/2010 11:15 |
|    22 | 10/10/2010 11:30 |
|    30 | 10/10/2010 11:45 |
+-------+------------------+
```

currently i'm using group by to get min,max,avg to take hourly reports like this:

```
+-----+-----+-------+------------------+
| min | max |  avg  |       Date       |
+-----+-----+-------+------------------+
|  10 |  15 | 12.75 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |
|  17 |  30 | 21.75 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |
+-----+-----+-------+------------------+
```

How i can calculate differences of last and first rows value in each group to generate something like:

```
+-----+-----+-------+------+------------------+
| min | max |  avg  | diff |       Date       |
+-----+-----+-------+------+------------------+
|  10 |  15 | 12.75 |    5 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |
|  17 |  30 | 21.75 |   13 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |
+-----+-----+-------+------+------------------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not showing the query you are using to obtain the results without `diff`. I'm assuming it is something like this:

```
SELECT
  min  = MIN(Value),
  max  = MAX(Value),
  avg  = AVG(Value),  -- or, if Value is an int, like this, perhaps:
                      -- AVG(CAST(Value AS decimal(10,2))
  Date = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
;
```

Also, you are not explaining what *first* and *last* mean. In this answer, it is assumed that *first* stands for *earliest in the group* (according to the `Date` value) and, similarly, *last* means *latest in the group*.

One way to throw in `diff` could be like this:

First, add two more aggregated columns, `minDate` and `maxDate`, to the original query:

```
SELECT
  min     = MIN(Value),
  max     = MAX(Value),
  avg     = AVG(Value),
  minDate = MIN(Date),
  maxDate = MAX(Date),
  Date    = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
;
```

Next, join the aggregated result set back to the original table on `minDate` and on `maxDate` (separately) to access the corresponding `Value`s:

```
SELECT
  g.min,
  g.max,
  g.avg,
  diff = last.Value - first.Value,
  g.Date
FROM (
  SELECT
    min     = MIN(Value),
    max     = MAX(Value),
    avg     = AVG(Value),
    minDate = MIN(Date),
    maxDate = MAX(Date),
    Date    = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
  FROM atable
  GROUP BY
    DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
) g
INNER JOIN atable first ON first.Date = g.minDate
INNER JOIN atable last  ON last .Date = g.maxDate
;
```

Note that the above assumes the `Date` values (at least those that happen to be first or last in their corresponding hours) to be unique, or you would get more than one row for some of the hours in the output.

An alternative, if you are on SQL Server 2005 or later version, could be to use window aggregate functions `MIN() OVER (...)` and `MAX() OVER (...)` to calculate `Value`s corresponding to either `minDate` or `maxDate`, before aggregating all the results similarly to how you are probably doing it now. Here's what specifically I'm talking about:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    Value,
    Date,
    GroupDate = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
  FROM atable
)
, firstlast AS (
  SELECT
    Value,
    Date,
    GroupDate,
    FirstValue = CASE Date WHEN MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate) THEN Value END,
    LastValue  = CASE Date WHEN MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate) THEN Value END
  FROM partitioned
)
SELECT
  min  = MIN(Value),
  max  = MAX(Value),
  avg  = AVG(Value),  -- or, again, if Value is an int, cast it as a decimal or float
  diff = MAX(LastValue) - MIN(FirstValue),
  Date = GroupDate
FROM firstlast
GROUP BY
  GroupDate
;
```

As you can see, the first [common table expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) merely returns all rows and adds a calculated column `GroupDate`, the one subsequently used for grouping/partitioning. So it essentially just assigns a name to the grouping expression, and that is done for better readability/maintainability of the entire query, as the column is later referenced more than once. This is what the first CTE produces:

```
+-------+------------------+------------------+
| Value |       Date       |    GroupDate     |
+-------+------------------+------------------+
|    10 | 10/10/2010 10:00 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |
|    11 | 10/10/2010 10:15 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:30 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:45 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |
|    17 | 10/10/2010 11:00 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |
|    18 | 10/10/2010 11:15 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |
|    22 | 10/10/2010 11:30 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |
|    30 | 10/10/2010 11:45 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |
+-------+------------------+------------------+
```

The second CTE adds two more columns to the above result. It uses [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) aggregate functions `MIN() OVER ...` and `MAX() OVER ...` to match against `Date`, and where the match takes place, the corresponding `Value` is returned in a separate column, either `FirstValue` or `LastValue`:

```
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
| Value |       Date       |    GroupDate     | FirstValue | LastValue |
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
|    10 | 10/10/2010 10:00 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |         10 |      NULL |
|    11 | 10/10/2010 10:15 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |       NULL |      NULL |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:30 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |       NULL |      NULL |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:45 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |       NULL |        15 |
|    17 | 10/10/2010 11:00 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |         17 |      NULL |
|    18 | 10/10/2010 11:15 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |       NULL |      NULL |
|    22 | 10/10/2010 11:30 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |       NULL |      NULL |
|    30 | 10/10/2010 11:45 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |       NULL |        30 |
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
```

At this point, everything is ready for the final aggregation. The `min`, `max`, and `avg` columns will be aggregated same as previously, and `diff` can now easily be obtained as the aggregated `FirstValue` subtracted from the aggregated `LastValue`. As you can see from the above result set, you can use various functions to get `FirstValue` and `LastValue` for the group: it could be `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `AVG` – any if these would do, because there's just one value in every group.

The main SELECT, however, as you can see, applies specifically `MAX()` over `LastValue` and `MIN()` over `FirstValue`. That is intentional. It's because this second suggestion doesn't really require `Date` to be unique, like the first one did, *but*, in case either `minDate` or `maxDate` does happen to have more than one associated `Value`, it would result in `FirstValue` or `LastValue` containing more than one value per group, something like this:

```
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
| Value |       Date       |    GroupDate     | FirstValue | LastValue |
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
|     9 | 10/10/2010 10:00 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |          9 |      NULL |
|    10 | 10/10/2010 10:00 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |         10 |      NULL |
|    11 | 10/10/2010 10:15 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |       NULL |      NULL |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:30 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |       NULL |      NULL |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:45 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |       NULL |        15 |
|    17 | 10/10/2010 11:00 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |         17 |      NULL |
|    18 | 10/10/2010 11:15 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |       NULL |      NULL |
|    22 | 10/10/2010 11:30 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |       NULL |      NULL |
|    30 | 10/10/2010 11:45 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |       NULL |        30 |
|    33 | 10/10/2010 11:45 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |       NULL |        33 |
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+
```

I assumed that in this situation it would be more natural to take the difference between the *greatest last* value and the *least first* one. You, however, should know better what rule to apply here, so you'll just change the query accordingly.

You can test both solutions at SQL Fiddle:

- [#1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf50/2)
- [#2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf50/4)

---

**Update**

Starting from SQL Server 2012, you can also use the [FIRST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) and [LAST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx) functions and substitute them for the CASE expressions in the `firstlast` CTE in my last query above, like this:

```
FirstValue = FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate ORDER BY Date ASC
                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
LastValue  = LAST_VALUE(Value)  OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate ORDER BY Date ASC
                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

In this case it will not matter whether you use MIN or MAX over `FirstValue` and `LastValue` later (in the main SELECT): each column will have exactly the same value (first or last `Value` accordingly) across all rows of the same `GroupDate` group, and so `MIN()` and `MAX()` would return identical results in each case.

In fact, you can get `diff` directly in the `firstlast` CTE and then, in the main query, just either aggregate it using MIN/MAX or add it to GROUP BY and reference it without aggregation, like this:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    Value,
    Date,
    GroupDate = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
  FROM atable
)
, firstlast AS (
  SELECT
    Value,
    Date,
    GroupDate,
    diff = LAST_VALUE(Value)  OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate ORDER BY Date ASC
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
         - FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate ORDER BY Date ASC
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  FROM partitioned
)
SELECT
  min  = MIN(Value),
  max  = MAX(Value),
  avg  = AVG(Value),
  diff,
  Date = GroupDate
FROM firstlast
GROUP BY
  GroupDate,
  diff
;
```

Moving one step further, you could obtain `min`, `max` and `avg` in `firstlast` as well, instead of the main query – using the counterpart window functions:

```
min  = MIN(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate),
max  = MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate),
avg  = AVG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate),
```

With these three additional columns and the previous change, the `firstlast` CTE will be returning a row set like this for your example:

```
+-------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+-------+------+
| Value |       Date       |    GroupDate     | min | max |  avg  | diff |
+-------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+-------+------+
|    10 | 10/10/2010 10:00 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |  10 |  15 | 12.75 |    5 |
|    11 | 10/10/2010 10:15 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |  10 |  15 | 12.75 |    5 |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:30 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |  10 |  15 | 12.75 |    5 |
|    15 | 10/10/2010 10:45 | 10/10/2010 10:00 |  10 |  15 | 12.75 |    5 |
|    17 | 10/10/2010 11:00 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |  17 |  30 | 21.75 |   13 |
|    18 | 10/10/2010 11:15 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |  17 |  30 | 21.75 |   13 |
|    22 | 10/10/2010 11:30 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |  17 |  30 | 21.75 |   13 |
|    30 | 10/10/2010 11:45 | 10/10/2010 11:00 |  17 |  30 | 21.75 |   13 |
+-------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+-------+------+
```

Note how `GroupDate`, `min`, `max`, `avg` and `diff` – the columns that you really need for the final set – are simply repeated across all rows that belong to the same group. That means that you can get rid of `Value` and `Date`, rename `GroupDate` to `Date`, slightly rearrange the columns, apply DISTINCT to the resulting set – and you have eliminated the last SELECT:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    Value,
    Date,
    GroupDate = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)
  FROM
    atable
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  min  = MIN(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate),
  max  = MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate),
  avg  = AVG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate),
  diff = LAST_VALUE(Value)  OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate ORDER BY Date ASC
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       - FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupDate ORDER BY Date ASC
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
  Date = GroupDate
FROM
  partitioned
;
```

Finally, it is also possible to move the `GroupDate` calculation into the same scope where `min`, `max` etc. are calculated. You can use CROSS APPLY for that and thus avoid the need for nesting a query entirely – in other words, this way you can get rid of the `partitioned` CTE as well. The *entire* query would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  min  = MIN(t.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY x.GroupDate),
  max  = MAX(t.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY x.GroupDate),
  avg  = AVG(t.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY x.GroupDate),
  diff = LAST_VALUE(t.Value)  OVER (PARTITION BY x.GroupDate ORDER BY t.Date ASC
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       - FIRST_VALUE(t.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY x.GroupDate ORDER BY t.Date ASC
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
  Date = x.GroupDate
FROM
  atable AS t
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Date), 0)) AS x (GroupDate)
;
```

and return the same results. You can test it [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cf50/6) too.

Answer (score -1):

Do what you're currently doing, and add column for

```
max(value)-min(value) as diff
```

Comment: That would work if min values corresponded to min dates, and same for max ones.